# How to get drive IDs like c0t1d0?

Tags: hard-drive, zfs, uuid

In the documentation to ZFS there are always drive IDs like c0t1d0 mentioned.
I only know about UUIDs which are much longer and /dev/sd?
How to get the IDs used?

Comment: Can you show or link to a specific example?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61017/remove-devices.html

Comment: That's for Solaris, not Linux. Look for similar OpenZFS or ZFS on Linux docs instead.

Comment: As @muru says, /dev/c0t1d0 is the Solaris equivalent of names like /dev/sd?.  Incidentally, you can see other kinds of ids in /dev/disk/by-id and I use the WWN (which comes from the drive hardware) for whole-disk ZFS.

Comment: well that answers my confusion. I didn't think about Solaris.